# What is the equivalent resistance of this bridge circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am trying but could not find any way of calculating the equivalent resistance of this circuit. Please help me. Should I use the Wheatstone Bridge equivalent resistance, the Y-$\Delta$ transform, or a more general method?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Answer (score 3):

This is solved using start-delta transformation and Delta-Star transformation like shown in the below picture
[image]

when you rewrite the circuit diagram it looks like this and you can notice delta network and star network in it.
[image]

Applying proper transformation reduces the complex network to simple network, then you can solve simple series/parallel combination network to get effective resistance between the node A and B.